# Specify AnyConnect Profile on Command Line

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I have a GUILess Linux Distro Client, so I'd rather avoid the Cisco GUI
I connect through the CLI with credentials and Host using:

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn
```

I then have the following error :

```
>> error: VPN establishment capability for a remote user is disabled
```

So I worked that around by inserting the `AllowRemoteUsers` entry into a new `Profile.xml` file
 that I created manually in folder `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile`

```
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/">
  <ClientInitialization>
    <WindowsVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</WindowsVPNEstablishment>
  </ClientInitialization>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

Problem is, I still got the error even after rebooting

So I guess that my profile file is not being taken into account

In a windows version documentation I saw that the `<profile-name>` could be passed to the VPN cli exe file as a parameter, so I was wondering if there was such a possibily on the cli... (however, the --help switch does not mention such a command)

Is there a way to make this work properly in Linux though CLI ?



PS : After spending a whole night haunting mailing lists archives and the like I ended up switching to **openconnect** which worked straight out in one single command without *any* configuration needed. 
(Still curious about the answer though.)